# How to check the radio button is selected or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am working on a quiz system. In that what I want to do is that the questions are collected from database and put as follow using php :

```
<div class="span12" style="margin-top:140px;">
<ul id="part">
<?php //print_r($quiz); 

$i = 1; 
foreach($quiz as $quiz)
{
    echo "<li id='div$i' style='display:none;'>
    <p style='font-size:20px;'><strong>Question $i </strong>: $quiz->Question </p>
    <br/><div style='margin-left:60px;font-size:14px;'>
    <input type='radio' name='op11' id='op1$i' value='1' style='opacity: 0;'>$quiz->op1<br/><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='op11' id='op2$i' value='2' style='opacity: 0;'>$quiz->op2<br/><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='op11' id='op3$i' value='3' style='opacity: 0;'>$quiz->op3<br/><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='op11' id='op4$i' value='4' style='opacity: 0;'>$quiz->op4<br/><br/></div>
    </li>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</ul>
<div class="span6">
<button id="next" class="btn btn-info btn-large" style="float:right;">Next &rarr; </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Now using jquery, when I click on next button then the value of selected answer is put into an array named as answers.

When the answer is selected then the array is being created corrected, but when I am not selecting any answers then the previous value is pushed into array.

For this purpose I am using following jquery function :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var items = $('ul#part li');
    var answers = new Array();
    if(items.filter(':visible').length == 0)
    {
        items.first().show();
    }
    $('#next').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        var active = items.filter(':visible:last');
        active.hide();
        var val = $("input:radio[name=op11]:checked").val();

        console.log(val)
        answers.push(val)
        var next = active.next();
        if (next.length)
             next.show();
        else{
            console.log(answers);
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

**For example :** I have three questions and I choose the answers 2,3,1 respectively then the array of answers is [2,3,1] that is correct but suppose I do not choose any answer of question no two, and the chosen answer of first and third question is 2,3 respectively then the created array according to my code is [2,2,3]. But I need that when I do not choose any answer then the value of that answer should be 0 means for above example the array should be [2,0,3]

How can I achieve it, please help me in correcting the code

Answer (score 0):

Use id for radio buttons:

example:

```
if(document.getElementById('op1$i').checked) {
  //radio button is checked
```

Comment: there is no element with ID equal to `op1$i`

Comment: `<input type='radio' name='op11' id='op1$i'` yes it does

Comment: No because $i is a php variable inside a loop, giving e.g on first iteration ID equal to: `op11` then `op12`, etc... That's said, this is a good advice to check for property `checked` of DOM node just like in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check is the current answer is selected. Try something like:

```
if ($("input:radio[name=op11]:checked").length == 1) {
    //One item checked with that name
    var val = $("input:radio[name=op11]:checked").val();
} else { var val=0; }                //or handle the error some other way
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem that if I check 2nd answer 2 and not select the 3rd question, then the array will be [1,2,2]

Comment: If you allow no answer for a question then add a specific value that tells you no answer was chosen (such as 0). If the user MUST check an answer then handle the "missing answer" with an alert("You must answer");

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = $("input:radio[name=op11]:checked").val();

if (typeof(val) !== "undefined" && val !== null){

    answers.push(val);

}else{
    answers.push(0);
}
```

You need to check it is not null or undefined. If it is (null or undefined) then add 0, otherwise add selected value.

Comment: This works only if I dont select the answer of first answer, but when I select the first answer and dont select answer of the next question then the answer of first question is put in the array